# QGIS map canvas: how to hide point of origin?

Tags: qgis, qgsmapcanvas

In the QGIS map canvas (main window), the point of origin of the coordinates is always shown as a small, blue square.
How to change the style of and hide this square?

I looked for the option in the menus View as well as Settings - options, without success.

[image]

Comment: Which QGIS version and CRS are we talking about?

Comment: QGIS 3.14, EPSG 3857.But it does not depend on version and EPSG, its the case in older versions and other CRS as well

Comment: Interesting, since I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Interesting - so might it have to do with a plugin?

Comment: Could be. But it also could be a setting I don't know about.

Comment: After updating all plugins, the symbol disappeared. So it has something to do with a plugin. On another QGIS installation, I deactivated the plugins one after the other and it seems that the "Bezier Editing" plugin created that square. When I updaten from 1.1.1. to 1.3.1, it disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it was the Bezier Editing Plugin that created the small blue square, see:

> QGIS Python Plugins Repository: Bezier Editing Changelog Version 1.2.1
>
> - fixed not to display blue marker when activated.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BezierEditing/version/1.3.1/