# Red marker cross on canvas can't be hidden or deleted

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I've somehow created an indelible red X on my map in QGIS. I can't select it, and switching off all the layers doesn't hide it. It doesn't show in the print layout. Its a constant screen size, eg mm.

Is it some feature I accidentally switched on?

How do I get rid of it?

Running 3.14.6 on W10

[image: QGIS screen shot, x marks a spot?]

Comment: Do you have some plugin installed that could cause that? I had a similar problem with the Bezier Editing Plugin that I solved by updating all plugins, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/376543/88814. Try that or even de-install the plugins one after the other to see if one of them causes the problem.

Comment: Try restarting QGIS.

Comment: Most probably the layer being edited is behind the rater image. Try to change the layer order to view it. Remember that QGIS draws the layers from the bottom to the top in the layer list.

Answer (score 2):

That is from a layer being edited.

You may have accidentally deleted the layer with the edit still on progress.

Restarting QGIS will resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

This red cross comes from the `Vertex Tool` on a point layer: select a point, move the mouse without clicking on the map, then `stop editing` -> the red cross remains.

To remove it, you can `start editing` the layer, use the `Vertex Tool` again and right click anywhere to dismiss the last not-terminated move.

If you don't know which layer it is, try restarting QGIS (as suggested by @MrXsquared and @HeikkiVesanto).